# How to set/get unsigned char * to and from std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I want to set the `unsigned char*` data to `std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>` and pass that pointer to a function and also in that function I want to get `unsigned char*` data from `std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>`.

Actually I want to read image data as follow.

```
FILE *fp=fopen("/data/FR/AjayPatil.jpg","rb");
if(fp)
{
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    data_size=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    jdata=( unsigned char *)malloc(data_size+1);
    if (!jdata)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return;
    }
    fread(jdata, data_size, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Now I have data in `jdata` as you see.
So how can I copy this data into `std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>`?

My Image structure is like as follow.

```
  typedef struct Image 
  {
       uint16_t width;
       uint16_t height;
       uint8_t depth;
       std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> data;
  }
```

Also after successful copy data following is the right way to get the data back?

```
     unsigned char *imagedata=data.get(); // here data means std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> data;
```

Comment: Why do you really need a `std::shared_ptr`, wouldn't a `std::vector<uint8_t>` suffice?

Comment: You don't "copy data into a pointer". You make the pointer point at data. There is no copyyng step.

Comment: as @user0042, you should use `std::vector`.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `uint8_t` at all? You seem to want to use `unsigned char` at both ends.

Comment: @Galik Isn't that the same?

Comment: @user0042 As far as I am aware the standard treats them differently wrt aliasing.

Comment: @Galik IIRC `uint8_t` simply is a `typedef` for `unsigned char`. How would that affect aliasing actually?

Comment: @user0042 I don't think the standard defines that `uint8_t` is an alias of `unsigned char`. I just did a quick check and can't find anything connecting them.

Answer (score 2):

The `image`'s data member `data` in the code below is an empty `std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>` (has no object to manage):

```
Image image;
```

#### Setting the object to manage

By calling the `std::shared_ptr`'s `reset()` member function you can set the managed object to that what `jdata` points to:

```
image.data.reset(jdata, free);
```

Note that you have to provide the `free` as the *deleter*, since the data pointed by `jdata` was allocated by means of `malloc`:

```
jdata=(unsigned char *)malloc(data_size+1);
```

Not providing `free` as the *deleter* would result in `delete` (i.e.: the *default deleter*) being used at `data`'s destruction.

#### Getting the managed object

In order to get the pointer to the managed object you can call the `std::shared_ptr`'s `get()` member function:

```
auto imagedata=data.get();
```