# fread() parameters 2 and 3

Tags: c, linux, stdio

What is the difference between:

```
fread( buf, sizeof buf, 1, file ); // 'file' is valid open 'FILE *'
```

and

```
fread( buf, 1, sizeof buf, file );
```

Parameters 2 and 3 are `size_t size, size_t nmemb` described as "fread() reads nmemb items of data, each size bytes long". I think the final number of bytes read must be `size * nmemb` but for some reason only second syntax (with size=1) is working for me.

Comment: Please define _does not work_. Does it compile? Both versions should work. Could you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: what is `buf` in your code?

Comment: @MichaelWalz The return value was always 0. I understood the reason from answers below.

Comment: @ChrisTurner `buf` is a buffer of some size. E.g. `char buf[1024];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is in the following two:

1. The return value is the number of elements which were actually read (zero up to `nmemb`). This is different in your two statement, if they succeed.
2. In the first case:

   ```
   fread( buf, sizeof(buf), 1, file )
   ```

   You will get all or nothing; `fread` cannot read something that is smaller than `sizeof(buf)` in case file is smaller.

   In the second case:

   ```
   fread( buf, 1, sizeof(buf), file );
   ```

   You allow `fread` to read as much bytes as possible, even if less than `sizeof(buf)` are available in the file. The number of elements (bytes in this case) actually read will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter specifies the size of element to be read. Third parameter specifies how many elements you want to read.

So in first case you want to read **1** element of size = **sizeof(buf)**.

In second case you want to read **sizeof(buf)** number of elements where each element is **1** byte. The second one can be used to read content of entire file as in this [How to set/get unsigned char * to and from std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216348/how-to-set-get-unsigned-char-to-and-from-stdshared-ptruint8-t) question.